# Разбиение аудиофайла на отрезки с использованием рядов Фурье python

Tags: python, анализ-данных, wav, фурье

Я новичек в анализе аудиофайлов. Задача стоит следующая: есть аудиофайл и его нужно разбить на отрезки равной длины, однако надо разбивать с помощью рядов Фурье. Если я что-то не так понял в задании - подскажите пожалуйста, если я правильно понял, то подскажите пожалуйста что это означает и как это можно сделать на Python или возможно вы знаете где об этом можно почитать.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужно разбить аудиоданные на куски (здесь Фурье ни при чём), и для каждого провести Фурье-преобразование, получив частотный спектр.

Comment: @MBo Да, я ошибся с вопросом, на самом деле вот что нужно сделать: есть аудиофайл со стандартной частотой дискретизации 44100 Гц. Нужно разбить его на отрезки(кадры) по 8192 сэмпла, причем нужно сделать перекрытие данных отрезков(кадров) в 50%. Как это можно сделать на Python, какие библиотеки и какие методы из них можно использовать для разбиения?

Comment: Ну я просто уточнение к вопросу внёс. Какие библиотеки Python лучше использовать - не подскажу. Знаю о существовании PyAudio.